# Getting value from validation method

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, validation

Currently I'm doing project regarding the edit text field validation. I have method that validate the input from edit text field (code is below).

```
- (BOOL) validatePhoneNumber: (NSString *) number {
    NSString *phoneRegex = @"[0-9]{10}";
    NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex];

    return [phoneTest evaluateWithObject:number];

    //[self validatePhoneNumber:yourTextField]
}
```

Then I have if else that checking the value. However, I don't know how to get the value from the method and compare it in the if else. Is there any suggestion or solution from this problem. I'm using `Objective-C` in XCode.

Below is my if else code.

```
if ([[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 1"] isEqualToString:@""] && [self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 1"]] && ![self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 2"]]) {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Invalid"
                                                              message:@"Please enter at least one valid contact."
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: @beyowulf    ![self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 2"] <--- what is this statement meaning?. Im sorry..Im still new with objective c....

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing it correctly however your if statement doesn't make sense. Currently it says: if contact 1 and contact 1 is a valid phone number and contact 2 is a not a valid phone number, show alert. Part 1 and part 2 of that if statement are mutually exclusive, so you will never get in the if block and the alert will never be shown.

Try changing

```
if ([[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 1"] isEqualToString:@""] && [self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 1"]] && ![self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 2"]])
```

to

```
if ([[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 1"] isEqualToString:@""] || (![self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 1"]] && ![self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 2"]]))
```

Comment: problem solve.. I just change your code a little bit.. to this one if (([[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 1"] isEqualToString:@""] || ![self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 1"]]) && ![self validatePhoneNumber:[_tempDict objectForKey:@"Contact 2"]])

Comment: not really solved it. because the contact 2 is not go throught the validation method...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want the if statement to be. Fairly certain the app freezing had nothing to do with the if statement I wrote. My statement says if contact 1 is empty or contact 1 and contact 2 are not valid phone numbers show alert. Yours says if contact 1 is empty or contact 1 is not a phone number and contact 2 is not a phone number  show alert. Yours is probably closer to what you want, but they are similar. You could save yourself some time by checking if phone number is nil or empty in validatePhoneNumber and returning no. Set a breakpoint to see when it's called.